# way points using open Street map in android

Tags: android, openstreetmap

I'm new to Open Street Map. I want to get the way points between source location and destination location using OSM in android. Is there any API in OSM to get the way points? I don't want to show the map on screen. Only need way points.

Someone please suggest any sort of solution or code for that.

Comment: May I know that how did you set the source and destination location in OSM?Could you provide the API ?

Comment: Source location is the device's current location and destination is what user enters.

Comment: I am using the API for single location http://www.openstreetmap.org/?mlat=latitude&mlon=longitude&zoom=12. Which API we have to use to set the pin for the both source and destination location for navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Just choose one of the many [online routers](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/online_routers) for OSM, for example GraphHopper or OSRM.